# Which jQuery callback fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-callback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Let's imagine you create some ajax requests in a for-loop like this:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      $.ajax({
        url : '/',
        success : function(){
          console.log('callback '+i+' fired!');
        }
      });
    }
});
```

Of course, the callback will log 'callback 10 fired' every time because the callbacks are executed asynchronous.
The question is: how can you know which callback fired?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rRwgW/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous self-invoked function will solve this closure issue:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      (function(i) {
          $.ajax({
            url : '/',
            success : function(){
              console.log('callback '+i+' fired!');
            }
          });
      })(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

create a scope with an immediately invoked function expression:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      (function(i){
        $.ajax({
          url : '/',
          success : function(){
            console.log('callback '+i+' fired!');
          }
        });
      })(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

By passing the current value of `i` as part of a closure:

```
$(function(){
    for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
      $.ajax({
        url : '/',
        success : (function(i){
          return function(){console.log('callback '+i+' fired!');}
        })(i)
      });
    }
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rRwgW/4/

Note: you don't actually need to wrap the entire ajax call in an IIFE, just the callback that needs to refer to the value of `i`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It works very well, but zerkms was just a bit faster, so I had to accept his answer.

Comment: @Jen-YaKovalev That's cool. For future reference, you don't need to explain your acceptance choices, we all understand. :) (My question was directed at the person who downvoted this, not you)